# Can't bind event to element, created by script

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I'm learning a pure JavaScript. Currently I'm exploring DOM objects, like WINDOW, DOCUMENT, ELEMENT and so on ...

I'm creating text fields on a fly and want to bind function to each element's event (`onfocus` or `onblur` for example), and pass self element as argument (like 'this').

The following script creates text field and binds it to a specific function.

```
var txt= document.createElement("input");
txt.type="text";
txt.value='0';
txt.size=12;
txt.style.textAlign="right";

txt.id="txt_"+self.count;

txt.addEventListener('focus', txt_focus(txt));
txt.addEventListener('blur', txt_blur(txt));
```

And below is the functions:

```
function txt_focus(txt){
txt.value=txt.id;
txt.style.backgroundColor='yellow';
}

function txt_blur(txt){
txt.style.backgroundColor='white';
}
```

This function recognizes given argument as element and sets its ID to value attribute, but it not affects to background color.
What have I missed?

Here is the entire HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
self.count =0;

function txt_focus(txt){
  txt.value=txt.id;
  txt.style.backgroundColor='yellow';
}

function txt_blur(txt){
  txt.style.backgroundColor='white';
}

function removeGroup(){
  if (self.count<1) {return;} 
  var parent=document.getElementById("myDiv");
  var fs_x =document.getElementById('fs_'+self.count);
  parent.removeChild(fs_x);
  self.count--;
}

function addGroup(){
  if (self.count>11) {return;} 
  self.count++;

  var parent=document.getElementById("myDiv");

  var fs=document.createElement("fieldSet");
  fs.style.borderRadius="7px"; 
  fs.style.height="45px";
  fs.id='fs_'+self.count;

  var l=document.createElement("legend");
  l.innerHTML="interval_"+self.count;
  l.style.color="darkgreen";
  l.style.fontStyle="italic";
  fs.appendChild(l);

  var d1= document.createElement("input");
  d1.type="date";
  d1.value='2014-05-01';
  d1.id='d1_'+self.count;
  fs.appendChild(d1);

  var d2= document.createElement("input");
  d2.type="date";
  d2.value='2014-05-22';
  d2.id='d2_'+self.count;
  fs.appendChild(d2);

  var txt= document.createElement("input");
  txt.type="text";
  txt.value='0';
  txt.size=12;
  txt.style.textAlign="right";

  txt.id="txt_"+self.count;

  txt.addEventListener('focus', txt_focus(txt));
  txt.addEventListener('blur', txt_blur(txt));

  fs.appendChild(txt);
  parent.appendChild(fs);
  fs.scrollIntoView();

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="hidden" id="hd1" value="0"> </input>
<button onclick="addGroup();"> Add a group</button>
<button onclick="removeGroup();"> Remove a group</button>


<div id="myDiv" style="padding:7px;position:relative;margin-top:15px;width:500px;height:500px;background-color:#ccbbcc;overflow-y:auto;border:1px red solid;border-radius:15px;">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Solution is desired in pure JavaScript, but JQuery solution is also interesting.

My second question is:

I've some background of basic JavaScript (like Math, strings, functions, arrays, classes and so on), and there I want your advice: Is there any necessity to dig deep into JavaScript details instead of jump to a JQuery?

Comment: Thanks, please get me the  link to this book, if it's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the difference between referencing a function and calling it. Whenever you add the parenthesis you call the function and return the result, and the default result is `undefined`.

In an event handler you want to reference the function only

```
txt.addEventListener('focus', txt_focus);
```

If you have to pass arguments, you'd use an anonymous function

```
txt.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    txt_focus(txt);
});
```

but here that doesn't make sense, as you're passing the element, which you could access with `this` inside the function instead

```
txt.addEventListener('focus', txt_focus);

function txt_focus() {
    var txt = this; // the element
}
```

Comment: In my simple I get elements Id txt.value=txt.id;  And I don't understand  "var txt = this;"  from where it gets "this"? I'll try it anyway

Comment: Inside every function there's a magical variable called `this` that reference the calling scope of the function. In this case it would reference the element, and doesn't really "come from" anywhere, it's just there. Start by reading some tutorials.

Comment: ADENEO >>> Amazing answer, thanks a lot wise man. and what you advice me about my second question? I love norway also due to Sissel and Magnus.